# Do I need to check in versionCode auto-incremented by build script?

Tags: android, git, versioning, development-environment, production-environment

My Android app, source controlled by Git, two branches, dev and master (for release). I added ant task to auto increment versionCode. We need to build dev occasionally for some quick verification and build master for release properly.

If every build increments versionCode, is it necessary to push the change to Git? I'm confused now, because I believe versionCode should got version controlled along with source code. But if I do so, the branch dev and master may get different versionCode and can cause further conflict while doing code merging.

If let the build machine cache the versionCode and incremente it based on that, looks like it's simple solution, but the versionCode in source would be never changed.

I want to know how to manage versionCode in common case for development and production environment.

Answer (score 0):

`versionCode` updates by a build script are just noise in version control. There's no point in versioning them.

Instead, consider creating a tag in your version control for each build so that the tag name and version code / version name can be easily mapped. This way there's less noise in version history and you can still know what code went to which build.

Comment: then how to map tag and version code? I believe versionCode should exist somewhere, otherwise can't map it.

Comment: but I understand the tag should be created by release instead of by build, besides, creating a new tag by every build is unacceptable

Comment: Well you don't *have to* tag every build. It's just a more practical alternative to checking in noisy manifest changes done by build script.